# Как вывести в терминал состояние кодирования ffmpeg если процесс запущен в фоне?

Tags: ffmpeg

Как в Ubuntu посмотреть состояние кодирования потока ffmpeg если сам процесс был запущен в фоновом режиме?

Нужно вывести примерно такую строку:

```
frame= 4870 fps= 26 q=31.0 q=36.0 size=    6111kB time=00:03:15.16 bitrate= 256.5kbits/s speed=1.05x
```

P.S. использовать `screen` не вариант.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кому интересно, нашел решение:

```
FFREPORT=file=ffreport.log:level=32 ffmpeg
```

и потом выводить последнюю строку в терминал:

```
cat ffreport.log | tail -n 1
```